# Firebase realtime database not returning any data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve an object the i added to my firebase realtime database But i am not getting anything and i dont know why . i made sure to implement and call firebase correctly .[image]
This is the response i get one i cal the database . 
and this is my imlimentation

```
<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*",
    authDomain: "*",
    databaseURL: "*",
    projectId: "*",
    storageBucket: "*",
    messagingSenderId: "*",
    appId: "*"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var dbRef = firebase.database();
var contactsRef = dbRef.ref("survey");
console.log(contactsRef)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a listener to retrieve the data:

```
var dbRef = firebase.database();
var contactsRef = dbRef.ref("survey");
contactsRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

`snapshot.val()` will give you all the data under node `survey`.

For more information check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once